# How to create function that returns the specifice dictionary? Not sure where to start

Tags: python

Complete the function to return a dictionary using `list1` as the keys and `list2` as the values.

Just completely lost on how to start this.

```
def createDict(list1, list2):
    # expected output: {'tomato': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow', 'lime': 'green'}  
    print(createDict(['tomato', 'banana', 'lime'], ['red','yellow','green']))        

    # expected output: {'Brazil': 'Brasilia', 'Ireland': 'Dublin', 'Indonesia': 'Jakarta'}
    print(createDict(['Brazil', 'Ireland', 'Indonesia'], ['Brasilia','Dublin','Jakarta']))

    # expected output: {'tomato': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow', 'lime': 'green'} 

    # expected output: {'Brazil': 'Brasilia', 'Ireland': 'Dublin', 'Indonesia': 'Jakarta'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to do it in the easiest pythonic way:

```
def createDict(list1, list2):
    return dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: mfw I type the answer, but "You can only post once every 3 minutes."

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple case of iterating over the first list, of keys, and assigning them the values of the second list. There are many ways to do this. The process looks something like this:

```
def createDict(list1, list2):
    outdict = {}  # define an empty dictionary to fill in and return
    for index, key in enumerate(list1):  # use items in list1, and their position
        outdict[key] = list2[index]      # assign the value
    return outdict
```

Of course, the most pythonic way to do this, is to use `zip`:

```
def createDict(list1, list2):
    return dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: Oh god thanks so much. I was not seeing the zip method! Sometimes its right in your face.

Answer (score 0):

E.g using dictionary comprehensions as described in this pep:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

```
def createDict(keys, values):
    return {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
```